# Cycling through splits and maintaining fullscren in tmux with neovim navigation

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard-shortcuts, vim, tmux

I use tmux with Neovim as a software developer (on Debian 10).

I'm having the following two issues and after much investigating still can't find a solution that suits me:

1. I would like to cycle through the splits infinitely (like tabs on a browser). Let's say I have 3 vertical splits open on Neovim, the only way for me to go to the first split from the last one is to cycle through backwards, I'd like to just navigate to the right from the last one be in the first split.

- [tmux with Neovim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JcfB.png)

2. tmux exits full-screen when I go "over the border", I'd like to prevent this. So I usually have Neovim at the top, taking about 70~80% of the screen, and a terminal at the bottom (like in the image above), but sometimes I need to go into full-screen Neovim, using tmux. Let's say that I have 2 vertical splits open in Neovim, what happens is that when I'm in the right split, and I accidentally navigate to the right (accidentally since there are no more splits to the right, I'd like to cycle them like described above), tmux exits the Neovim full-screen, and I don't want this to happen, I only want it to happen if I go DOWN (which is where the terminal is), or maybe if I just use the same keys combination I used to go full-screen (in my case is Ctrl-s + z).

- [Full-screen Neovim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db3vM.png)
- [After going "over the border"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQVsL.png)

This is my .tmux.conf:

```
# tmux display things in 256 colors
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

# Automatically renumber tmux windows
set -g renumber-windows on

# Unbind default prefix and set it to Ctrl+s
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-s
bind C-s send-prefix

# Split window and fix path for tmux
bind / split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind - split-window -v -c "#{pane_current_path}"

# Pane movement shortcuts
# bind -n C-h select-pane -L
# bind -n C-j select-pane -D
# bind -n C-k select-pane -U
# bind -n C-l select-pane -R

# Smart pane switching with awareness of Vim splits.

# See: https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator
is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
    | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'"

bind-key -n 'C-h' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-h'  'select-pane -L'
bind-key -n 'C-j' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-j'  'select-pane -D'
bind-key -n 'C-k' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-k'  'select-pane -U'
bind-key -n 'C-l' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-l'  'select-pane -R'

tmux_version='$(tmux -V | sed -En "s/^tmux ([0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?).*/\1/p")'
if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$tmux_version < 3.0" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
  "bind-key -n 'C-\\' if-shell \"$is_vim\" 'send-keys C-\\'  'select-pane -l'"
if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$tmux_version >= 3.0" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
  "bind-key -n 'C-\\' if-shell \"$is_vim\" 'send-keys C-\\\\'  'select-pane -l'"

bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-h' select-pane -L
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-j' select-pane -D
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-k' select-pane -U
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-l' select-pane -R
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi 'C-\' select-pane -l

# Resize pane shortcuts
bind -r H resize-pane -L 5
bind -r J resize-pane -D 5
bind -r K resize-pane -U 5
bind -r L resize-pane -R 5

# Enable mouse support for switching panes/windows
setw -g mouse on

bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -in -selection clipboard'

set-option -g history-limit 10000

set-option -sg escape-time 10
```

Comment: If you use 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator' (I use it with vim, but maybe you have it for neovim too) then you can do `let g:tmux_navigator_disable_when_zoomed = 1` to not break out of zoom when you're moving around in vim.

Comment: I do use it! Thank you, that solves the second issue!

Answer (score 1):

If you use 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator' I think this will work for you:

#### First issue:

In my system (using tmux 2.6 on Ubuntu 18.04, and tmux 2.7 on Debian Buster), I
am able to cycle through panes as you describe. E.g. if I'm in the right-most
pane, and I use `ctrl-l` to go 'right', I end up in the leftmost pane. Putting this in your tmux conf should do the trick:

```
# Smart pane switching with awareness of Vim splits.

# See: https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator
is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
    | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'"

bind-key -n 'C-k' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-k'  'select-pane -U'
bind-key -n 'C-j' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-j'  'select-pane -D'
bind-key -n 'C-h' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-h'  'select-pane -L'
bind-key -n 'C-l' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-l'  'select-pane -R'
```

Since I use fzf in vim, and have set `ctrl+j/k` to move up and down the list, I
have an additional check (`is_fzf`) to trigger that behaviour instead of
navigating the split. If you want to do the same the code is:

```
# Smart pane switching with awareness of Vim splits and fzf windows.

# See: https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator
is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
    | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'"

# See: https://github.com/keeganlow/dotfiles/blob/master/.tmux.conf
is_fzf="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
  | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?fzf$'"

bind-key -n 'C-k' if-shell "($is_vim || $is_fzf)" 'send-keys C-k'  'select-pane -U'
bind-key -n 'C-j' if-shell "($is_vim || $is_fzf)" 'send-keys C-j'  'select-pane -D'
bind-key -n 'C-h' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-h'  'select-pane -L'
bind-key -n 'C-l' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-l'  'select-pane -R'
```

#### Second issue:

In you vimrc, you can use:

```
let g:tmux_navigator_disable_when_zoomed = 1
```

to not break out of zoom when you're moving around in vim.

#### Edit - my whole .tmux.conf

```
# reload the tmux.conf and display a message to that effect
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display "Reloaded .tmux.conf"

# source colorscheme
set -g default-terminal 'screen-256color'
# source-file ~/.tmux_light.conf

# remap prefix from CTRL-B to CTRL+Spacebar {{{
set -g prefix C-Space
unbind C-b
# }}}

# configure default limits/times {{{
# Set scrollback buffer to 10000
set -g history-limit 10000
# No delay for escape key press
set -sg escape-time 0
# When using repeatable commands (like resizing) repeat-time is the duration of
# the window (in milliseconds) for which a repeat can be made (default is 500)
set -g repeat-time 1000
# If I want to switch to another pane while in a fzf list, I can do prefix+q,
# then hit the number of the pane I want. Make those numbers last a bit longer.
# (I can always press escape to make them turn off immediately)
set -g display-panes-time 3000
# }}}

# pane and window indexing {{{
# Set the base index for windows to 1 instead of 0
set -g base-index 1
# Set the base index for panes to 1 instead of 0
set-window-option -g pane-base-index 1
# }}}

# pane navigation {{{
# allow the vim pluging 'tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events' to work
set -g focus-events on
# split panes using | and - {{{
%if "#{==:#{host},office}"
# ubuntu 20.04 
bind '\' split-window -h
%endif
%if "#{!=:#{host},office}"
# ubuntu 18.04 and debian buster
bind \ split-window -h
%endif

bind - split-window -v
unbind '"'
unbind %    
# }}}

# Pane resizing with prefix + H/J/K/L: {{{
bind -r H resize-pane -L 5
bind -r L resize-pane -R 5
bind -r K resize-pane -U 3
bind -r J resize-pane -D 3
# }}}
 
# Smart pane switching with awareness of Vim splits and fzf windows. {{{

# See: https://github.com/christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator
is_vim="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
    | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?g?(view|n?vim?x?)(diff)?$'"

# See: https://github.com/keeganlow/dotfiles/blob/master/.tmux.conf
is_fzf="ps -o state= -o comm= -t '#{pane_tty}' \
  | grep -iqE '^[^TXZ ]+ +(\\S+\\/)?fzf$'"

bind-key -n 'C-k' if-shell "($is_vim || $is_fzf)" 'send-keys C-k'  'select-pane -U'
bind-key -n 'C-j' if-shell "($is_vim || $is_fzf)" 'send-keys C-j'  'select-pane -D'
bind-key -n 'C-h' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-h'  'select-pane -L'
bind-key -n 'C-l' if-shell "$is_vim" 'send-keys C-l'  'select-pane -R'

# go to last pane (like b# in vim)
bind '#' select-pane -l
# }}}
# }}}

# visually select and yank to system clipboard {{{
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -sel clip -i'
# like visual block mode
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi r send-keys -X rectangle-toggle
# I think I might overwrite the lower case p for 'previous window', since I
# can just use next/numbers to swtich
bind P paste-buffer
# }}}
```

Comment: I actually had this in my tmux config file (the fix for the first issue), but it's still not working, I'll post it in full in the post because maybe there's something conflicting with that that I'm not noticing.

Comment: hmmm, I don't see anything very different than mine that would obviously cause the behaviour - I'll post my whole tmux conf and maybe you can try it out to see if the issue remains. I commented out a single line where it goes off to source some colour settings, but that can't be the issue. I hope this helps!

Comment: So weird, I'm actually using your full tmux config file and it still doesn't work, I wonder if it has something to do with Neovim's config...

Comment: huh.. but for me it also works when I even don't have vim open at all - just a few tmux panes... so I don't know how it could be due to Neovim (although I haven't used Neovim, so maybe I'm missing something...). I hope you figure it out!

Comment: I just used your config and the pane cycling works as usual for me... so it's for sure not something about that...

Comment: Must be something with Neovim then, thank you, at least we've narrowed it down to that :)